# Programmatically Add Menu Item in Component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, menu-item

I am trying to create a component where the user can add a menu item to an existing Menu after creating the article (or selecting from a list of article). The closest I could come across to an example of sort was the answer linked below but it was for 2.x and looks the way to go. But one thing I noticed was there was nothing to show that it added any data to the #__assets table.

Am I missing something here but I remember that when a menu item is created when I add one from the backend, it also inserts a record into the assets table. So if I wanted to insert a new menu item, would I have to insert the relevant data to the #_assets table separately?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651075/programatically-create-menu-item-in-joomla?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

firstly - menu items are not put into the assets table, so this question is about a non-existent problem.  The link provided in the question gives the correct answer for joom 2.5 and 3.x. but for reference here is an example in the prepareTable of a model.

```
$menuTable = JTableNested::getInstance('Menu');

// which menu you want to add to - 
$menutype = 'thisismymenusname';

// this is heading menu item but what data you have and require will vary per case - just look at an appropriate row in yr menu table
$menuData = array(
  'menutype' => $menutype,
  'title' => $table->alias,
  'alias' => $table->alias,
  'path' => $table->alias,
  'type' => 'heading',
  'component_id' => 0,                  
  'language' => '*',
  'published' => 1,
);

// this item is at the root so the parent id needs to be 1
$parent_id = 1;
$menuTable->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');

// save is the shortcut method for bind, check and store
if (!$menuTable->save($menuData))
{
  $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This works well. Just be mindful of the menutype and parent_ids if you are going to add this to a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Not really a solution, but an idea:

I recently learned about [Kazaam!](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/menu-editors/20057), a plugin that creates a menu based on your category- and article structure.

As the website states, `All code is open source, and you are completely free to make changes.`. Looking at the source code, you should be able to see how it works, and maybe use parts of the code for your own project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give the plugin a go although a lot of people seem to be having problems with it and will mark it as an answer if I can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most readable code that worked for me is here => https://webkul.com/blog/menu-item-joomla-rebuild-automatically/

Comment: I don't like the double `preg_` calls in the `while()` loop.  I think a single `preg_replace_callback()` call is cleaner.  https://3v4l.org/5IBXU