# Creating a menu using php

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item

I'm trying to create a menu item in joomla 3.x using php

I've been trying to get this code to work:

```
$menuItem = array(
    'menutype' => 'client-pages',
    'title' => "new Menu",
    'type' => 'component',
    'component_id' => 22,
    'link' => 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$articleid,
    'language' => '*',
    'published' => 1,
    'parent_id' => $parent_id,
    'level' => 1,
);

$menuTable = JTable::getInstance('Menu', 'JTable', array());

$menuTable->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');

if (!$menuTable->save($menuItem)) {
    throw new Exception($menuTable->getError());
    echo "exception thrown";
    return false;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($menuTable);
echo "</pre>";
```

It doesn't throw errors and the print_r menu table makes it look like it's going to create the menu item

```
Joomla\CMS\Table\Menu Object
(
    [parent_id] => 5536
    [level] => 1
    [lft] => 327
    [rgt] => 328
    [alias] => new-menu
    [_location:protected] => last-child
    [_location_id:protected] => 
    [_cache:protected] => Array
        (
            [rebuild.sql] => 
SELECT id, alias
FROM #__menu
WHERE parent_id = %d
ORDER BY parent_id, lft
        ) ....
```

However no menu item is created - can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Programmatically update Menu Item in Component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/19149/12352) , [Programmatically Add Menu Item in Component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/5104/12352) , [Programmatically Create Menu Item in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12651075/2943403) , [How to add new admin menu items without reinstalling component in joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8733833/2943403) ...some itemised details in the answer: [Adding Joomla menu for new component directly in DB (Joomla 2.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217217/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, perhaps just an oversight on bringing your code to the JSE platform here, but...

```
$menuTable = JTable::getInstance('Menu', 'JTable', array());
```

You are passing in an empty array.

```
$newMenu = new stdClass();
$newMenu->title="blah";
$newMenu->type="component";
etc
```

Then you can do:

```
$menuTable        = JTable::getInstance('menu', 'JTable');
$menuData         = (array)$newMenu;

$menuTable->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');
$menuTable->save($menuData);
```

You are missing the following required properties in your `$menuItem` array.

- alias
- path
- template_style_id
- params

I'd also suggest doing this in a try/catch, which will be easier to diagnose.

```
try
{
    if ($menuTable->save($menuItem))
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    throw new Exception('You might want to substitute this for another function, but $e will be your error exception', 500);
}
return $menuTable->id;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I couldn't get it to work - I don't think I understand how $menuData         = (array)$jMenus;   fits into the code

Comment: Apologies, updated code, it should read `$menuData = (array)$newMenu`

Comment: thanks got it to work -

Comment: I don't know that the empty _$config_ array as the 3rd param of `getInstance()` is a problem. https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class , https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Table.Table.html#method_getInstance and `save()` will accept an object or an array as the first param: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Table.Table.html#method_save  It is important that we do not misinform the OP and researchers. Can you show me the docs page that shows the required data for the `$menuData` @Grant?

Comment: @mickmackusa both the $prefix and $config are optional as per menu.php model. The reason I _know_ about those missing properties is through my own trial and error. The code in my OP is the code I am currently using - never did find the requirements per se, but I do suspect the lack of `alias` and `params` was the root cause of the issue here as these are _always_ set in both the model and menu helpers.

Comment: @grantg  I found that you don't need alias if your using the Joomla class.  It creates it and amends it from the title.  Of course if you want a specific alias then it needs to be suppllied.

Comment: @Grant I am still researching/delving into this question and your advice.  I think I am in agreement 3 of the 4 required properties that you have listed.  According to https://docs.joomla.org/Tables/menu, the `template_style_id` column has a default values -- so this can be safely omitted.  I would've assumed that `note` was necessary to declare, maybe it becomes an empty string. Likewise with `img`.